# Is there a way to track upload progress in Selenium without use of HTML/CSS elements?

Tags: python, selenium, http, upload, jquery-file-upload

Is there a way to track progress of a file upload using Python > Selenium without the use of HTML/CSS elements? Looking for a general solution that works on many sites, but don't have a clue where to start.

In Python's request library progress can be ascertained because you're streaming in chunks, but I have no clue where to begin in Selenium or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to looking for information about upload progress in performance logs

```
# Doesn't work for Firefox. Only Chrome
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)

# upload file

# watch performance logs
for perf_entry in driver.get_log("performance"):
    perf_entry["message"] = json.loads(perf_entry["message"])["message"]
    # check perf_entry
```

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough. Great find, with lots of other useful information.
Please note everyone, this doesn't work for Firefox. Only Chrome.